# Is there a way to open href links in new tab without updating all the links with target="_blank code manually?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have anchor links throughout a table I am working on.

```
<div id="table1">
<td>See example <a href="#john">john</a>; <a href="#julie">julie, an</a>; <a href="#sam-ham">sam-ham</a>; <a href="#state-names">state names</a>.</td></div>
```

These links need to be opened in a new tab by adding the following code - target="_blank". As a result, the link should look like this

```
See example <a href="#john" target= "_blank">john</a>;
```

Would it be possible to add the code without manually updating hundreds of links?

Please note that I aslo have other links on the page

Comment: There’s [`<base>`: The Document Base URL element](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base#attr-target). Keep in mind that forcing a specific way to open links is bad UX.

Comment: <base> would add code to all the links on the page? I want to add the code only on a table.

Comment: @magicsinger `document.getElementById('table1').querySelectorAll('a').forEach(el => el.target = "_blank");`

Comment: I think this will add to all links on the page and not just the table? <div id="table1">

Comment: @magicsinger I updated my comment to provide you what you want. It will first get the element with id `table1`, then get all descendant anchors of the table.